# How to use a project with no entry point in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm porting a project over to Visual Studio and running into this problem.  I have a project that I want to build and use as part of my solution, but it won't build itself.

When I build the solution, that project gives the error "No entry point".

The other main project that will rely on this library project then gives linker errors, since this won't build.  What is the correct approach for this?

For reference, the code I'm trying to build is from [here](http://vision.middlebury.edu/MRF/code/), and the library is `imageLib.zip` from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the project properties page, and set "Configuration type" to "Static library" or "Dynamic library", rather than "Application". You might also need the `/NOENTRY` flag.

Answer (score 1):

In Project Properties, Configuration -> General -> Configuration Type should be either Static library (.lib) or Dynamic Library (.dll).

Answer (score 1):

probably, project that you are trying to port is static library, or DLL, both don't have a "classic" main function. Try to change Configuration type, or define entry point.